# How do i create a simple expandable list in android

Tags: android, list, expandable

i want to make an expandable list in android ( with only one group ) that has item1, sub-item1, seperator, item2, sub-item2, sperator and so on..., where item1 and item2's values are taken from an array of numbers and sub-item1 and sub-item2's values are taken from an array of strings. I did attempt to find out but im pretty new and dont understand most of it(yet):D.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html link for expandable list.

All The Best

Comment: haha yeah ive been looking at them on there and the http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList3.html one is the layout i want but i cant figure out how to put stuff from my arrays into the boxes instead of their stuff because they use that 'map<>' stuff and sod knnows what that is :P any ideas?